# Error "Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported" assigning a form object

Tags: forms, vb6

I have two forms: Form1 and Form2

Form1 creates a new instance of Form2:

```
Dim NewFrm as new Form2
Newfrm.show
```

I need to update or call a sub from NewFrm (Form2) to the calling form, Form1.

I have tried creating a Property Let in Form2 as so:

```
Dim CalledFromFormInstanceFrm as Form1

Public Property Let CalledFromFormInstance(oValue As Form1)
    CalledFromFormInstanceFrm = oValue
End Property
```

So, in Form1 I'm now doing

```
Dim NewFrm as New Form2
NewFrm.CalledFromFormInstanceFrm=Me
NewFrm.Show
```

when it get to the Public Property Let in Form, it works - but the CalledFromFormInstanceFrm is failing with an error:

> Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic'.

Googling, the error seems to point to people using other 3rd party ActiveX's not Forms in VB6.

I have also tried change the Property Let to

```
Public Property Let CalledFromFormInstance(oValue As Form)
```

and changing the declaration to

```
Dim CalledFromFormInstanceFrm as Form
```

Just in case it didn't like specifics about a Form and just accepted the Form object.

I'm stuck - though the first Property Let , allows me to use it so I think it might be allowed in VB6, I'm just not sure of the syntax I should be using - the equivalent in .net works fine but .net is a million miles away from VB6 as far as an improved language.

Any idea?

Comment: Try changing your property to `Property Set` since you are working with objects.  Likewise, use the `Set` keyword inside the property itself and on the main form.

Comment: Not addressing the direct question, but another way to 'call' back to Form1 would be to define an event on Form2, add a matching event handller to Form1 for Form2, then raise the event in Form2. The event handler does what it needs to do and can even 'return' data via the event parameters/arguments, if need be.

Answer (score 4):

`Set` is the thing you need when dealing with object references so it should be:

```
Dim CalledFromFormInstanceFrm As Form1

Public Property Set CalledFromFormInstance(oValue As Form1) '//set
    Set CalledFromFormInstanceFrm = oValue '//set
End Property
```

Called as:

```
Dim NewFrm As New Form2
Set NewFrm.CalledFromFormInstance = Me '// set
NewFrm.Show
```

Also note that you try to use the private variable: `NewFrm.CalledFromFormInstanceFrm = Me` instead of the public property `NewFrm.CalledFromFormInstance`.

Comment: Gordon Bennett - thats worked a treat ! I forgot I have to Set everything in VB6, to be honest, I never attempted to use OOP properly in VB6, I always ended up using Form1.whateveritis without having to create it, but since discovering it .NET ive had forms popping out all over the place lol - thats a life saver - I wished I had asked this 3 hours ago, would have saved myself some time! THank you Brian and thank you Alex - both stars! :)